# Ionic app rejected from app store because it wouldn't load

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, app-store

I recently submitted my app to the Apple app store, but it was rejected..

> Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness
>
> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone
>   running iOS 11.4.1 on Wi-Fi.
>
> Upon launch, the activity indicator spins indefinitely

I've tested the app on multiple iPhones, from 6 to X and it works fine. It takes maybe 4-5 seconds to load past the splash screen, but that shouldn't be a reason for rejection?

I did update my `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` recently and I noticed that the launch became slower? My `config.xml` said I was on v `^1.1.16` but my `package.json` said I was on `^2.0.2`, not sure if that is an issue? There's also a v `2.1.3` out now..

But as I said, I have no idea what the problem could be as it works fine on my iPhones..

The important parts of my `config.xml` looks like this.. not sure if it shows anything that might lead to the answer:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="30000" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="60000" />
<preference name="target-device" value="handset" />

<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    ...icons/splashscreens
</platform>

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.1.16" />
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" />
<plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="^2.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
<allow-navigation href="http://192.168.9.77:8100" />
<allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.27:8100" />
<allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.5:8100" />
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
    <string>To connect you to your local university!</string>
</edit-config>
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription">
    <string>To let you upload images!</string>
</edit-config>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^4.11.0">
    <variable name="GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="To connect you to your local university!" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="1.0.5" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.0.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy" spec="^2.2.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.1.2" />
<plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" spec="^4.0.8" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-google-analytics" spec="^1.8.6">
    <variable name="GMS_VERSION" value="16.0.3" />
</plugin>
<engine name="browser" spec="^5.0.4" />
<engine name="android" spec="^7.0.0" />
<engine name="ios" spec="^4.5.5" />
```

and since my `<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />` is false, in my `app.component.ts` file I have the following line of code that hides the splashscreen:

```
constructor(
public zone: NgZone,
private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        if (user) {
          this.rootPage = HomePage
          this.splashScreen.hide();
        } else {
          this.rootPage = LoginPage
          this.splashScreen.hide();
          console.log("Not logged in")
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Is there any clue in here why this might not be working? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Jane. Have you figured out how to fix it? My app is rejected due to the same reason

Answer (score 0):

"Upon launch, the activity indicator spins indefinitely"

if you are using ionic loader or spinner then handle it properly

ex. (not the full code just example)

```
this.spinnerDialog.show();

http.req().then((data)=>{
   this.spinnerDialog.hide();
}).err((error)=>{
   this.spinnerDialog.hide();
})
```

you have to handle the spinner, loader or activity indicator properly